# Solve the equation by using logarithms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

The equation is

$64(12)^{8x} = 195$

the steps I have done so far.

- $12^{8x} = 195/64$
- $8x \cdot \ln(12) = \ln(195/64)$
- $8x = (\ln(195/64))/(\ln(12))$

not sure how to divide $8x$ to get $x$ by itself for the final answer with the ln's

Comment: Wait a minute --- you've done all the log stuff, now you're down to $8x=A$, and you can't solve that for $x$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson that is correct. I took a break from math for about 8 months and I know you divide 8 on both sides, but the ln's are confusing me.

Comment: Don't let them confuse you! Dividing by $8$ is dividing by $8$, no matter what the other side of the equation looks like. What would you do if it were $8x=93/42$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson x = 8(93/42)?

Comment: @GerryMyerson oh its x = 93/336

Comment: I've corrected a typo on the RHS of your 2nd step. It was $(195/64)\ln$.

Comment: Yes, and that $336$ was just $8\times42$, right? And you could have written $(8)(42)$ instead of $336$, right? So, ${93\over(8)(42)}$, right? So, can you finish the log problem off now?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yup! thank you

Comment: For the record, I suggested an edit improving the title and the format and adding a tag, but [it was rejected](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1996061).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you divide $8x = (\ln(195/64))/\ln(12)$ you get $x = (\ln(195/64))/(\ln(12)(8))$. The 8 only affects the bottom denominator of equation when you divide a fraction. thank you @GerryMyerson

Comment: It's better to write $x=\frac{\ln(195/64)}{8\ln(12)}$ using the code `$x=\frac{\ln(195/64)}{8\ln(12)}$`. See  [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @AméricoTavares thanks, I don't understand how that code works yet. Do you know of any great tutorials?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).